# multi 1d heatmap plot re-creation

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, heatmap

I'm trying to re-create an image I have seen, basically needs to be identical.

If anyone could point to in the right direction that would be great. It represents density of mutations across a chromosome (scale is Million base pairs)

[Chromosome SNP density map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz7nn.png)

[image]

I have the data for this in a format like this

```
Chromosome Chromosome_position Number_of_SNPs

Chr1\t100000\t345\n

Chr1\t200000\t265\n
etc.
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Ryan

Comment: What is the "density of mutations"? Is it the density of `Number_of_SNPs`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent yes Number_of_SNPs would determine the colour of each location on the heatmap. This would represent the density of SNPs in each location along the chromosome

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your density but here is an example for an "ordinary" density.

```
library(data.table)
# simulated data
n <- 1000
DT <- data.table(Chr = rep(c("Chr1","Chr2"),each=n),
                 v = c(rgamma(n, 2, 3), rgamma(n,10,3)))
# construct density data 
DT2 <- DT[, {dty <- density(v, from = 0, to = max(v))
             list(x=dty$x, 
                  z=cut(dty$y, c(seq(0,1,by=0.1), Inf)))}, 
          by="Chr"]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DT2, aes("",round(x,1))) + geom_tile(aes(fill=z)) + 
  facet_grid(~Chr) + xlab(NULL) + ylab("something") + 
  scale_fill_viridis_d("density")
# I take round(x,1) because that does not work with x (looks like a bug)
```

[image]